# Bump: sudo gcore gives 'insufficient privilege' on a chrome tab process

Tags: macos, google-chrome, sudo, gcore

Original post August 21, 2018: [sudo gcore gives 'insufficient privilege' on a chrome tab process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51940247/sudo-gcore-gives-insufficient-privilege-on-a-chrome-tab-process/52169948#52169948)

---

I am only user on this macbook pro (high sierra) so I'm the only administrator.

Anytime I go into terminal and type "gcore PID" or "sudo gcore PID" I get the following:"gcore: insufficient privilege". (The actual PID I want is 7415)

The only reason I'm even attempting to do this is because yesterday I was filling out important information for a scholarship on a webpage in google chrome and an error occurred and I lost everything I typed. ....so I followed the instructions located here...https://superuser.com/questions/975744/how-do-i-recover-information-ive-typed-into-a-website-after-i-accidentally-lost

Yesterday I installed xcode, installed homebrew, and installed gcore. I also have user permission to read and write the folder "/etc" and the file "sudoers".

I have not deleted my chrome browsing data but I did restart my computer last night. I'm assuming the information I seek in the ram is gone?

Nonetheless I still want to figure out why the terminal says "gcore: insufficient privilege" after entering "sudo gcore 7415" when I am an administrator?

Thank you in advance to anyone who can answer this!

Comment: I had success using the Homebrew version of gcore rather than the system version that is preinstalled.  Once you have Homebrew installed you can just enter brew install gcore.  From there, you can run the Homebrew gcore from /usr/local/Cellar/gcore/##### VERSION HERE###/bin/gcore.